# (Python) Gaussian Bernoulli RBM on computing P(v|h)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, rbm

**Context:**

I am implementing Gaussian Bernoulli RBM, it is like the popular RBM but with real-valued visible units.

True that the procedure of sampling hidden values `p(h=1|v)` are the same for both, i.e.

[image]

**Problem:**

My problem is in coding (using Python) `p(v|h)`, which is,

[image]

I am a little bit confused as to how *N()* works. Do I simply add Gaussian noise using the data's standard deviation to `b + sigma * W.dot(h)`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in terms of `scipy`'s methods, that equation is simply `v = stats.norm.rvs( loc=b + sigma * W.dot(h), scale=sigma )`, not sure what is ambiguous here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notation *X* ~ *N*(μ, σ²) means that *X* is normally distributed with mean μ and variance σ², so in the RBM training routine, *v* should be **sampled** from such a distribution. In NumPy terms, that's

```
v = sigma * np.random.randn(v_size) + b + sigma * W.dot(h)
```

Or use `scipy.stats.norm` for better readable code.